# Given n Resistors and A Desired Resistance, R, find the setup that would create an equivalent Resistance Closest to R

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, runtime

I wanted to see if I could make a program where given n resistors and a desired resistance, the program finds the setup of parallel and series resistors such that the equivalent resistance  is as close as possible to the desired resistance. I came up with a very naive approach where the program loops through the list of resistors and either takes the current resistor in series with the current Req, in parallel, or doesn't use it at all. In order to accommodate for the case where a resistor isn't currently used but used later in the circuit, I ran the recursive function on every permutation of the list. I know this is incredibly inefficient but I only plan on doing this for at most, 4 resistors and for that, the program works well enough.

The problem I'm having is that this program, when it decides to use a resistor, either puts it in parallel or in series with Req which isn't always the case. You could have two resistors in series be in parallel with Req. I'm not sure how to account for these cases.

```
import itertools
A, B, D = [], [], []

def eqResistor(L, Req, S, count):
    for i in range(len(L)):
        #either take next resistor in series
        eqResistor(L[1:], Req + L[0], S + " in series with " + str(L[0]), count + 1)
        if Req != 0:
            #take it in parallel
            eqResistor(L[1:], 1/(1/Req + 1/(L[0])), S + " in parallel with " + str(L[0]), count +1)
        #or don't use it at all
        eqResistor(L[1:], Req, S, count)

    A.append(Req)
    B.append(S)
    D.append(count)  




def optimalResistance(L, R):
    M = list(itertools.permutations(L))
    #since it's possible that we use a resistor later on that we left out before
    #one way to accommodate for this is to run through every permutation of the
    #list of resistors
    #this is incredibly inefficient but for what I'm doing I think it should be ok
    
    for i in M:
        eqResistor(i, 0, "0", 0)

    #find best setup
    C = [abs(a-R) for a in A]

    index = 0
    mini = 50000
    for i in range(len(C)):
        if C[i] == mini:
            #if eq resistances are the same
            # take the one with the smaller number of resistors
            if D[i] < D[index]:
                C[i] = mini
                index = i
        if C[i] < mini:
            mini = C[i]
            index = i
    return "With these resistors, the closest equivalent resistance is: " + str(A[index]) + " by having " + B[index]


#doesn't find optimal solution in this case:
R1 = 4
R2 = 4
R3 = 9
R4 = 1
print(1/(1/(R1+R2) + 1/(R3+R4)))
print(optimalResistance([R1,R2,R3,R4], 1/(1/(R1+R2) + 1/(R3+R4))))
```

So say we have a 4 resistors, R1 = 4, R2 = 12, R3 = 10, R4 = 7. But, say for our circuit, we really needed a 15 ohm resistor. So this program would take in the list of resistors we have and the desired  resistor and try to come up with a setup of parallel and series resistors that will create an equivalent resistance as close as possible to 15 ohms. Then, we can use that setup in place of a 15 ohm resistor in our circuit.

The output of this program gives:

"With these resistors, the closest equivalent resistance is: 14.869565217391305 by having 0 in series with 4 in series with 12 in parallel with 7 in series with 10".

In general, this program works most of the time but say we wanted a equivalent resistance of 8.24. The program tells us:

"With these resistors, the closest equivalent resistance is: 8.117647058823529 by having 0 in series with 10 in parallel with 7 in series with 4"

But, the closest equivalent resistance is actually ((R1 + R2)^-1 + (R3+R4)^-1)^-1 = 8.24242. The program doesn't think of finding "intermediate" equivalent resistances and putting them in parallel/series with each other.

Comment: The title of your question should better indicate what the problem is about. The current subject is so generic, it will not attract many viewers.

Comment: sorry it should be better now though it is still too long i guess

Comment: Please post some sample input along with the desired output from that sample.

Comment: No problem! Here you go.